# how to validate the data of ckeditor in CI

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to validate the data of ckeditor. Is there any way to validate it in CodeIgniter? I have tried like this.

In View:

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-10"> 
        <textarea class="ckeditor" name="desc" id="editor" required><?php echo set_value('desc', ''); ?></textarea>
        <span class="error"><?php echo form_error('desc'); ?></span>
</div>
```

In controller:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('desc', 'Desc', 'required');
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
    $this->add_Coachs();
} else {

    $rs = $this->functional->insertBlog();

    if ($rs == true) {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('blog', 'Your Blog Submitted Successfully.Thank You!');
        redirect('Wall');
    } else {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('blog', 'Blog Not Submitted');
        redirect('Wall');
    }
}
```

But here it executes the false condition. Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong? Is there any way to resolve this problem?

**Edited :**

In model :

```
public function insertBlog() {

    $full_name = $this->session->userdata('first_name') . " " . $this->session->userdata('last_name');
    $email = $this->session->userdata('email');
    $data = array(
        'user_id' => $this->input->post('user_id'),
        'full_name' => $full_name,
        'email' => $email,
        'desc' => $this->input->post('desc'),
        'create_date' => date('Y-m-d h:i:s', now()),
        'modify_date' => date('Y:m:d h:i:s'),
        'start_date' => date('Y:m:d h:i:s'),
        'end_date' => date('Y:m:d h:i:s'),
        'status' => "Deactive",
        'userby' => $this->input->post('user_id')
    );
    $rs = $this->db->insert('ult_latest_blog', $data);
    return $rs;
}
```

Comment: Can you check `var_dump($rs);` ?

Comment: Can you show me `insertBlog();` model code?

Comment: Which version of CKeditor and are you using any javascript that runs `onsubmit` or other button click?

Comment: No i didn't use any javascript functions..

Comment: @ Naim Malek  Please check my edited code.